# openpyxl save to instance field django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, openpyxl

I would like to insert an excel sheet file every time i submit a form using POST. File however, must to be **previously generated** in views and afterwards, inserted into an **instance.field.**

Model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    attachment = \
    models.FileField(\
        _("Sheet"), 
        upload_to='uploads/', 
        max_length=100,
        blank=True, null=True)
   ...
```

View:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook

class Order1(View):
     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)

            #Creating sheet
            book = Workbook()
            sheet = book.active
            sheet['A1'] = 56
            sheet['A2'] = 43
            now = time.strftime("%x")
            sheet['A3'] = now

            #Calling model field instance - What im doing wrong here?
            obj.attachment = book.save("sample.xlsx")

            #Saving model instance
            obj.save()

            #Some return - required for AJAX
            return JsonResponse({"status": "OK"})
```

All saves besides attachemnt field. What im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly save the file like that. You will need to open it in binary read mode after saving and then you can pass it to the File constructor:

```
from django.core.files import File
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook

class Order1(View):
     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)

            #Creating sheet
            book = Workbook()
            sheet = book.active
            sheet['A1'] = 56
            sheet['A2'] = 43
            now = time.strftime("%x")
            sheet['A3'] = now

            #Calling model field instance - What im doing wrong here?
            book.save("sample.xlsx")
            with open('sample.xlsx', 'rb') as f:
                obj.attachment.save("sample.xlsx", File(f), save=False)

            #Saving model instance
            obj.save()

            #Some return - required for AJAX
            return JsonResponse({"status": "OK"})
```